# Allow only all language alphanumeric in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to make an input that allows all language letters, English, non-English, etc. except special characters, in total:

**Allow:**

- All language alphanumeric
- `CTRL / ALT / SHIFT / SPACE / BACKSPACE / SPACE` and etc.

**Disallow:**

- Special Characters such `_-/!@#$%^&*()+=`, etc. like emoji and more.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgsfjuhs/104/)**

```
$('#txtFirstName').on('keydown paste',function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) ||
              (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90) ||
              (key >= 48 && key <= 57))) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Well, everything looks great and works fine on desktop, but it is not working on mobile devices like Android or iPhone keyboard, **when you use a non-English language keyboard it won't let the user type**, so I guess it can't recognize keyboard key code, am I right? Can this issue be fixed? Or can you share another solution for this? Any idea?

Comment: Why disallow typing when you can use a specific format (via a regex) for your input that must be matched?

Comment: @Vivick How can i define a regex pattern for all language, like Arabic, Chinese and Japanese and etc? got a solution?

Comment: any example or more explain? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: "all languages" is an ambitious spec. you would have to look into the concept of [Unicode character categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm). Could you just go with a list of exclusions, allowing everything but... ? Alphabets with lots of characters like Chinese use compositing input methods and won't be captured by just looking for a key code.

Comment: @dlatikay I solved this problem with another way and logic, but thanks for reply, maybe this help for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just make this logic reverse, so I wanted to allow alphanumeric in all languages, but it's hard to detect all languages' `keyCode` unless using a Unicode range, but I write a regular expression to disallow all possible special characters in desktop and mobile phones keyboard.

```js
$('#txtFirstName').on('keydown paste', function(e) {
  var pattern = /[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:..’“'"<>,€£¥•،٫؟»«\{\}\[\]\\\/]+/gi;
  if (pattern.test($(this).val())) {
    alert('not allowed');
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(pattern, ''));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtFirstName" value="">
```

This solution helped me out this time, but it is not the best solution but I'm still working on it. It's free to add your desired special character to prevent it.